# How to optimize Tesseract for 1 specific font/style

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fonts, tesseract

First things first, I use the tesseract wrapper for C# from charlesw on github and here is an example of of my problem:

The upload might be rotated with 90 degrees-

[image: The upload might be rotated with 90 degrees]

This is what Tesseract gives me back:

[image: Tesseract Result]

Thats like.. nothing :/ 
I tried the following things (with more or less success.. well.. mostly less):
Set DPI to 300, 
pure B&W (like this sample picture), 
cut away all the borders, 
increased contrast

I think that the main issue is this 'broken' font. Is there a way to train this wrapper for this font and if so, how?
It will always be the exact same font and roughly the same arrangement for all my images.

Thank you very much for your time, I really appreciate it.